# Decoding ampersand hash strings (&#124&#120&#97)etc

Tags: python, html, decode

The solutions in other answers do not work when I try them, the same string outputs when I try those methods.

I am trying to do web scraping using Python 2.7. I have the webpage downloaded and it has some characters which are in the form `&#120` where 120 seems to represent the ascii code. I tried using `HTMLParser()` and `decode()` methods but nothing seems to work. 
Please note that what I have from the webpage in the format are only those characters. 
Example:

```
&#66&#108&#97&#115&#116&#101&#114&#106&#97&#120&#120&#32
```

Please guide me to decode these strings using Python. I have read the other answers but the solutions don't seem to work for me.

Comment: They aren't valid [character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview): they are missing the terminating semicolon. But once those semicolons are added, that example decodes to `Blasterjaxx `

Comment: Try to specify encoding explicitly while you downloading those pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing, you may wish to convert that data to valid HTML [character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview) so you can parse it in context with a proper HTML parser.

However, it's easy enough to extract the number strings and convert them to the equivalent ASCII characters yourself. Eg,

```
s ='&#66&#108&#97&#115&#116&#101&#114&#106&#97&#120&#120&#32'
print ''.join([chr(int(u)) for u in s.split('&#') if u])
```

**output**

```
Blasterjaxx
```

The `if u` skips over the initial empty string that we get because `s` begins with the splitting string `'&#'`. Alternatively, we could skip it by slicing:

```
''.join([chr(int(u)) for u in s.split('&#')[1:]])
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct format for character reference is `&#nnnn;` so the `;` is missing in your example. You can add the `;` and then use HTMLParser.unescape() :

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import re
x ='&#66&#108&#97&#115&#116&#101&#114&#106&#97&#120&#120&#32'
x = re.sub(r'(&#[0-9]*)', r'\1;', x)
print x
h = HTMLParser()
print h.unescape(x)
```

This gives this output :

```
&#66;&#108;&#97;&#115;&#116;&#101;&#114;&#106;&#97;&#120;&#120;&#32;
Blasterjaxx
```

Comment: This solution is deprecated, please refer to solution presented below (add semicolons first): https://stackoverflow.com/a/55985595/318618

Comment: Thank you for the tip about having to unescape those characters.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77738709/handlebars-net-inserts-japanese-characters-and-converts-them-to-unicode-decimal

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, use the `html` module:

```py
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('&#66&#108&#97&#115&#116&#101&#114&#106&#97&#120&#120&#32')
'Blasterjaxx '
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html