# Unicode string comparison in python 2.7, how to normalise html elements like &#163; != \xa3

Tags: python-2.7

I have a database and a fresh unicode input.

```
if new_field != old_field:
    update_db(new_field)
```

In PyCharm both appear identical, even when I hover and expand the "view" box I copy paste them into notepad and they are identical, eg:

```
u"<li>Laundromatic doofer drier £200 on collection</li>"
u"<li>Laundromatic doofer drier £200 on collection</li>"
```

What is causing the miscomp is the underlying encoding of the pound sign (why can't it have a pythonic single way?). They are both unicode; `type(new_field) is unicode`.

I got so frustrated by this that I broke each field (a load of sales blurb) down  as so:

```
>set(old_field.split()) ^ set(new_field.split())

u'£200'  # from new_field
u'&#163;200'  # from old_field
```

Is there a better way to compare unicode in python (I'm using 2.7)? i.e. something more universal than

```
if new_field != old_field.replace(u"&#163;", u"\xa3")
```

*The new field came from the web then was passed to `bleach.clean` where I had to pass it to `.encode("utf-8")` because it was apparently producing (sqlite3) illegal characters to represent nbsp. The old field has been fetched from sqlite before passing it through `bleach.clean` (as an afterthought), which did not require `.encode("utf-8")`, since sqlite only stores unicode.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
new_field = u'\xa3200'
old_field = u'&#163;200'
h = HTMLParser()
equiv = h.unescape(old_field) == h.unescape(new_field)
equiv2 = h.unescape(old_field) == new_field  # To be clear only ampersand hash strings get replaced.
print(u"   {} == {} ? {} and {}".format(new_field, old_field, equiv, equiv2))


   £200 == &#163;200 ? True and True
```

This is how I did it, credit to Fabich, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38481378/866333.

One can't have too many "Decoding ampersand hash strings" type questions; Google just gives me the pound sign back!